# Unable to access FETCH response data

Tags: javascript

i've created an endpoint for a personal api (that is obscured in the code), and it works well, i can fetch correctly and i get the array in console.log

the problem is that i can't access the data to populate a table, i can't figure what is wrong.

my code :

```
export default class lastExtensions extends Page {

  oninit(vnode){
    super.oninit(vnode)
    this.loading = true
  }

  oncreate(vnode) {
    super.oncreate(vnode);
    app.setTitle(app.translator.trans('justoverclock-extiverse-ext-api.forum.pagetitle'));
    app.setTitleCount(0);

    const settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "url",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "header1": "header1",
        "header1-key": "000000000000000000000jsn213b8019cc43"
      }
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      this.ext = response.slice(0,14);
      console.log(this.ext)
      this.loading = false;
      m.redraw();
    })
  }

  view() {
   
    return (
      <div className="lastExtPage">
        {IndexPage.prototype.hero()}
        <div className="container">
          <div className="sideNavContainer">
            <nav className="nav IndexPage-nav sideNav">
              <ul>{listItems(IndexPage.prototype.sidebarItems().toArray())}</ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="content sideNavOffset">
              <h1 className="lastExtTitle">
                {app.translator.trans('justoverclock-extiverse-ext-api.forum.pageTitle')}
              </h1>
              <p className="pagedescription">{app.translator.trans('justoverclock-extiverse-ext-api.forum.pageText')}</p>
              <div className="containerExtensions" id="extList">
                {this.ext.map((ext) =>{   // HERE THE PROBLEM
                  {console.log(ext)}
                  return (
                    <tr class="listaEst">
                      <td class="tdone">{I WANT DATA HERE}</td>
                      <td class="tdtwo">{I WANT DATA HERE}</td>
                      <td class="tdthree">{I WANT DATA HERE}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

i can't figure why i can't map and access my fetch response to populate a table...what i'm doing wrong?

this.ext console log is:

```
[
    {
        "name": " aaaaaa ",
        "desc": "bbbbbbbbb.",
        "totalDownload": " 0 downloads ",
        "image": "https://aaa.png",
        "url": "https://aaa.png"
    },
{
        "name": " aaaaaa ",
        "desc": "bbbbbbbbb.",
        "totalDownload": " 0 downloads ",
        "image": "https://aaa.png",
        "url": "https://aaa.png"
    },
{
        "name": " aaaaaa ",
        "desc": "bbbbbbbbb.",
        "totalDownload": " 0 downloads ",
        "image": "https://aaa.png",
        "url": "https://aaa.png"
    }
]
```

Comment: can you please console this.ext and attach the result in the body as well

Comment: `this` will be the jquery's ajax object

Comment: done, added the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function, so that 'this' refers to 'this' in outer scope.

```
$.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
    this.ext = response.slice(0,14);
    console.log(this.ext)
    this.loading = false;
    m.redraw();
})
```

To fix the other problem, initialize the data

```
oninit(vnode){
  super.oninit(vnode);
  this.loading = true;
  this.ext = [];
}
```

Comment: i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when i call map later

Comment: thanks! i can finally access all :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this example so you know you're referencing the right `this`:

```
oninit(vnode){
    ...
    this.ext = null;
}

setExt = (data) => {
    this.ext = data;
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    setExt(response.slice(0,14));
      ...
})
```

Comment: @Jkarttunen's answer is better I think